# How do we remove just the "+" sign from mobile number ,

Tags: php

I am collecting mobile number in a registration form with +919xxxx. But for sending SMS through API my SMS provider don't allow + prefix instead they allow country code with mobile number
So for this instance alone I need to remove the + prefix and Post mobile number in API string so which code I should use in PHP ?

Any advice greatly appreciated

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

Comment: `ltrim` will work for this specific case. However you may want to consider that phone numbers may also be submitted with spaces, dashes, periods etc. If you wanted to make sure it's digits only, you'd `preg_replace('~[^\d]~', '', $number)` and remove any non-digits.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code it will work and remove "+" from your number

```
    $str = "+912789635241";
    $remove = trim($str,"+");
    echo $remove;
```

Comment: If there is a `+` sign in the phone number I think it must already be a string

Comment: ok then use this code it will trim "+" from the variable and provide the result.

Comment: Am using code like below
  $mno = $_POST['mobile'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$number =$code.$mno; // combines +91 and mobile number which will be like +91996xxxxx so ple tell me how I can trim from $number ? Advice much appreciated

Comment: @shijumax  just replace the variable in the example with the one from your own code which you want to trim, e.g. `$code = trim($_POST["code"], "+");`

Comment: Is it like ,   $ new =trim($number, '+');

Comment: replace $str variable to your $number variable it will give result like this  91996xxxxx

Comment: just a quick question ,, can i trim the session code like below                                   $code =  trim($_SESSION['country_code_se'], "+")

Comment: @shikumax why not try it and see? But if the session value is a string, then of course you can...you can trim any string

Comment: can you please tell me what's you session value ??

Comment: yes you can remove this "+"  using my code.